# Find a normal vector onto the line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, parametric, orthogonality

How can I find normal vector on the given line. For example if I have a line $3x - 5y = 1$, what would be the normal vector of this line? I am not sure whether it's useful or not, but we have one more random point on the line perpendicular to the given line, $P = (3,-2)$.

Point $P$ is just a random point onto the other line, not a intersecting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal vector of a 2-dimensional line will have the direction vector of an orthogonal line to it.

$$L: 3x-5y=1 \iff y = \dfrac{3}{5}x-\dfrac{1}{5}$$

So any line having slope $-\dfrac{5}{3}$ will be orthogonal to $L$. In other words, all normal vectors to $L$ will be a non-zero multiple of $\langle3,-5\rangle$. In general, a normal to

$$ax+by=c$$

will be a scalar multiple of $\langle a,b\rangle$.

If you're looking for the unique orthogonal line passing through your given $P$ then you use the point in the **point-slope** equation of a line.

$$y-(-2) = \dfrac{-5}{3}(x-3)$$

Comment: According to your definition of `2x+y=10` has `(2,1)` as `(a,b)` , so scalable multiple would be `4x+2y=10` as it has `(4,2)` as (a,b), which certainly is not perpendicular

Comment: @A.B Your comment is incorrect. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iv6arjd7vu

Answer (score 3):

Any line can be written in the form
$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0$$ and the perpendicular vector is clearly $(a,b)$. So from yor equation you can just read it off, the perpendicular is $(3,-5)$.

Comment: Nope, it's a plane's equation you just mentioned and (3,-5) would be a normal vector on that plane. And I need normal on the line.